# How to Secure Coding Guideline work with sonar rule?

Tags: java, sonarqube

1. click "Rules" link
2. Search "xpath"
3. click the Java XPath rule that is not deprecated
4. click "create" Fill in "name"/"key"/"Description"/"Message" as "should not use                                  Collections.synchronizedMap" ,                 change status as "ready" , set xpathQuery as //IDENTIFIER[@tokenValue='synchronizedMap']
5. click "create" button
6. click "edit" and notice "xpathQuery" field is empty which is unexpected.
   fill the field "xpathQuery" with //IDENTIFIER[@tokenValue='synchronizedMap'] again
7. click "save" button
8. click "edit" and notice "xpathQuery" field is missing totally , which is unexpected.
   run sonar runner again code that contains "Map test = Collections.synchronizedMap()"
   no issue detected which is unexpected.

how to create sonarQube rule for java security guidelines,I can't create rule this way..
i can't generate xpathQuery.. what can I do for this?